# Find out recursive pattern in a string java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching

In one of my interview I had asked one program on java string, I am unable to answer it. I don't know it is a simple program or complex one. I have explored on the internet for it, but unable to find the exact solution for it. My question is as follow,

I have supposed one string which contains recursive pattern like,

```
String str1 = "abcabcabc";
```

In above string recursive pattern is "abc" which repeated in one string, because this string only contains "abc" pattern recursively.

if I passed this string to a function/method as a parameter that function/method should return me **"This string has a recursive pattern."** If that string doesn't have any recursive pattern then simply function/method should return **"This string doesn't contain the recursive pattern."**

Following are probabilities,

```
String str1 = "abcabcabc"; 
//This string contains recursive pattern 'abc'

String str2 = "abcabcabcabdac"; 
//This string doesn't contains recursive pattern

String str2 = "abcddabcddabcddddabc";
//This string contains recursive pattern 'abc' & 'dd'
```

Can anybody suggest me solution/algorithm for this, I am struggling with it. What is the best way for different probabilities, so that I implement?

Comment: what his this got to do with recursion? a repeating pattern, sure, but recursion?

Comment: In your 3rd string there's `abc` and `dd` as well as `dddd`. Does that mean there can be more than 1 patterns that can be mixed in any way?

Comment: your second string contains a, b, c, ab, bc, abc, ... as repetitive Strings

Comment: You need a regex, I believe, `if (s.matches("^(abc|dd)+$") {return true;} else { return false; }`

Comment: A 'recursive pattern' for a number sequence is something like "A(n) = A(n - 1) + k" for example 1, 4, 7, 10, ... (k = 3). Not sure how you could extend that to strings easily. Pretty certain they meant "repetitive pattern" or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-substring-pattern/discuss/)

> ```
> public boolean repeatedSubstringPattern(String str) {
>   int l = str.length();
>   for(int i=l/2;i>=1;i--) {
>       if(l%i==0) {
>           int m = l/i;
>           String subS = str.substring(0,i);
>           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>           for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
>               sb.append(subS);
>           }
>           if(sb.toString().equals(str)) return true;
>       }
>   }
>   return false;
> }
> ```
>
> 1. The length of the repeating substring must be a divisor of the length of the input string
> 2. Search for all possible divisor of str.length, starting for length/2
> 3. If i is a divisor of length, repeat the substring from 0 to i the number of times i is contained in s.length
> 4. If the repeated substring is equals to the input str return true

Comment: It does actually. I feel the OP isn't describing the problem accurately. The question asks to check if there is a repetitive pattern in a string and not couple of repetitive patterns. https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-substring-pattern/description/

Comment: No. It doesn't. I agree that there may be a typo in the third example, but the code you give does not match that example. There is definitely something missing in the description of the problem, but just because it superficially looks like a problem of finding string repeats does not mean that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is not in Javascript. However, problem looked interesting, so attempted to solve it in `python`. Apologies!

In `python`, I wrote a logic which worked [Could be written much better, thought the logic would help you]

Script is

```
def check(lst):
    return all(x in lst[-1] for x in lst)

s = raw_input("Enter string:: ")
if check(sorted(s.split(s[0])[1:])):
    print("String, {} is recursive".format(s))
else:
    print("String, {} is NOT recursive".format(s))
```

Output of the script:

```
[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ python dup.py 
Enter string:: abcabcabcabdac
String, abcabcabcabdac is NOT recursive
[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ python dup.py 
Enter string:: abcabcabc
String, abcabcabc is recursive
[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ python dup.py 
Enter string:: abcddabcddabcddddabc
String, abcddabcddabcddddabc is recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved using a part of the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

The idea is to build a 1-D array with each entry representing a character in the word. For each character `i` in the word we check if there is a prefix which is also a suffix in the word up `0 to i`. The reason being if we have common suffix and prefix we can continue searching from the character after prefix ends which we update the array with the corresponding character index.

For `s="abcababcababcab"`, the array will be

```
Index : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
String: a b c a b c a b c 
KMP   : 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

For `Index = 2`, we see that there is no suffix which is also the prefix in the string `ab` i.e) up until `Index = 2`

For `Index = 4`, the suffix ab(Index = 3, 4) is same as the prefix ab(Index = 0, 1) so we update the `KMP[4] = 2` which is the index of the pattern from which we have to resume searching.

Thus `KMP[i]` holds the index of the string `s` where prefix matches the longest possible suffix in the range `0 to i` plus 1. Which essentially means that the a prefix with length `index + 1 - KMP[index]` exists in the string previously. using this information we can find out if all the substrings of that length are the same.

For `Index = 8`, we know `KMP[index] = 6`, which means there is a prefix(`s[3] to s[5]`) of length `9 - 6 = 3` which is equal to the suffix(`s[6] to s[8]`), If this is the only repetitive pattern we have this will follow

For a clearer explanation of this algorithm please [check this video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTJr8OvyEVQ).
This table can be build in linear time,

```
vector<int> buildKMPtable(string word)
{
    vector<int> kmp(word.size());
    int j=0;
    for(int i=1; i < word.size(); ++i)
    {
        j = word[j] == word[i] ? j : kmp[j-1];
        if(word[j] == word[i])
        {
             kmp[i] = j + 1;
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            kmp[i] = j;
        }
    }
    return kmp;
}

bool repeatedSubstringPattern(string s) {
    auto kmp = buildKMPtable(s);    
    if(kmp[s.size() -1] == 0) // Occurs when the string has no prefix with suffix ending at the last character of the string
    {
        return false;
    }
    int diff = s.size() - kmp[s.size() -1]; //Length of the repetitive pattern
    if(s.size() % diff != 0) //Length of repetitive pattern must be a multiple of the size of the string
    {
        return false;
    }
// Check if that repetitive pattern is the only repetitive pattern. 
    string word = s.substr(0, diff);
    int w_size = word.size();
    for(int i=0; i < w_size; ++i)
    {
        int j = i;
        while(j < s.size())
        {
            if(word[i] == s[j])
            {
                j += w_size;    
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the 'parts' in advance, then the answer could be [Recursive regular expressions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html), it seems.

So for `abcabcabc` we need an expression like `abc(?R)*` where:

- abc matches the literal characters
- (?R) recurses the pattern
- A * to match between zero and unlimited number of times

The third one is a little trickier. See [this regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/c08yuW/1) but it looks like:

`((abc)|(dd))(?R)*`

where we have either 'abc' or 'dd' and there are any number of these.

Otherwise, I don't see how you could determine from just a string that it has some undefined recursive structure like this.